# Obtain Windows Logon Token using WebAuthN API

Tags: windows, azure-active-directory, webauthn, fido, fido-u2f

I am on an Azure domain where users are able to logon using their FIDO2 security keys.  I would like to be able to obtain a user's Windows Logon token using their security key.

There are some very good C++ samples of Authentication (Assertion) of keys (
https://github.com/aseigler/HelloSample/blob/master/hello/hello.cpp )  but I have not found any way of using the returned Assertion information to obtain a user's logon token that can then be used for impersonation. This should be possible since a user can use that same security key login or unlock the Windows workstation.

I see some very interesting exported functions in the Windows WebAuthN.dll like WebAuthNGetPlatformCredentials or WebAuthNDecodeAccountInformation.  Unfortunately, these functions do not seem to be documented.

Has anyone managed to obtain a Windows Logon Token using WebAuthN or have any idea of how this can be done?

Comment: I use impersonation.

Comment: Nick, can you please explain what you mean?  Normally I use CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials to prompt a user for their credentials, it returns a buffer "ppvOutAuthBuffer" that can be used with LsaLogonUser to obtain the user's token.  I am trying to fingure out what can be used with the information returned by WebAuthNAuthenticatorGetAssertion to obtain a Logon token that can be impersonated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use Impersonation when users access IIS web apps and connect to Web services or SQL Server on the IIS server.

```
        impersonationContext = currentWindowsIdentity.Impersonate

        'Insert your code that runs under the security context of the authenticating user here. 

        impersonationContext.Undo()
```

PS: If you're asking users for their credentials,...ever, the systems you're using should be burned and you should be fired immediately.

Comment: Hi Nick,  Thanks for your input.  The C++ program is not connecting to Web services but running locally on the system.  I am not asking for anyone's credentials.  Once a user is authenticated using "WebAuthNAuthenticatorGetAssertion" I am hoping to be able to impersonate that user user locally.  
Although my call to "WebAuthNAuthenticatorGetAssertion"seems to go successfully, the Current Windows Identity does not change - it is still that of the person that ran the program to call the function.